# multiple input and multiple output in ssis with executing bat file

Tags: c#, ssis

I have a problem as below please try to give me some hint or help.

1. I am implementing a vb code in ssis to reduce the time. so i need to do exactlly the same as in vb project.
2. it is getting input from user and checking the name of file on the basis of file name it choose another file as input from 2 other files of 2nd type.
3. And then it does some operarions and provide outputs.
4. I have 3 kind of zip files to input as first type.
5. I have to unzip these files.

Problem: So the problem is how to unzip the file. And how to handle the possibility of multiple input and output. Is it possible to give the sorce file at run time..?
How to do it usning .bat file

Solution: I supposed following solution.

Get input through a script manager(script component as a source). Unzip the first file and read the file and save the output in output columns.

get second file from flat file manager but here i have problem i need to know the name of zip file accordinglly i have to choose the 2nd file. So how to choose the flat file connection manaeger's file name at run time.?

A bit Solved:
                Now i am using Script Task before data flow tasks. I am getting the file name from user and then accordinglly execute the respective dataflow. But i am having problem in filebrowsing
    OpenFileDialog openPathDial = new OpenFileDialog();
i am having error in the following.
  =>  DialogResult diloResFile = openPathDial.ShowDialog();

Error:= Error: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Threading.ThreadStateException: Current thread must be set to single thread apartment (STA) mode before OLE calls can be made. Ensure that your Main function has STAThreadAttribute marked on it. This exception is only raised if a debugger is attached to the process.

Thanking you
I know its too much but your hint will work to siplify the problem.

Nitesh

Comment: SSIS is not really made for user input. For example to interactively have a user enter a file name you have to install SSIS and visual studio on their computer and then it has to perform the work, including moving the data from the file to the computer then to the database. It's a bad idea. How many users will you have running this process? What outputs do you have? Does it just load the selected file to the database? Are you OK to install 3rd party unzip software (i.e. 7-zip) You'll need to explain step 2 & 3 further preferably with examples.

Comment: Hi,     
   I have 3 kind of first file type in Zip. So i get that first type of file and unzip it. according to that file name i will select the 2 input file. That's the idea i want to take input as. To unzip the file i can use script component. but i am confused about to perfome the first process. How to get 2nd input ..?
I heared about .bat file processing.
Thanks for your help..!

Comment: Another question ..?
What if i use script task and branch from script task...?

Comment: I think @ElectricLlama you just i ask questions on every post..
You asked me questions on my previous pots as well but after that you were never there...

Is that so..?
Thank you

Comment: I ask questions for many reasons: 1. To test whether the poster is going to bother sticking around to accept my answer 2. To help the poster think about their question and possibly solve their own problem. 3. To ascertain whether a solution I have in mind is worth solving. 4. To clarify the question.

Comment: With regards to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21605109/data-conversion-in-ssis. You figured it out, plus I'm probably in a different timezone.

Comment: So i have another question: why are tou converting an existing VB project to SSIS? A VB project is great for user input. Am SSIS project is bad for user input. If you have a performance problem in your VB project you should fix that - SSIS won't fix it. Your explanation of the files still makes no sense to me sorry.

Comment: Yeah that's true you are in different time zone. But i was just asking because after asking questions you didn't show up. Sorry it was not meant to heart you.

Comment: I am going to ssis because it will save my time. Now current project is taking 23 minuts. Later it should take about 5 min.

Comment: @ElectricLlama It's solved a bit now. Now i am having a problem in openfilebrows. As i used script task before all other tasks to decide which 2nd input i should take, and unzip the file.

Comment: I'm sure you can optimise your VB project to run in 5 minutes. You'll need to try and explain your issue clearly in your question so we can try and solve it.

Comment: Now i simplized the problem
As Below answer.. But still getting some Errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i Normalized the problem as below.

1. I am using Script Tast in Control flow And asked to enter the file Name Using a form in C#. I am getting file name as browsing the file.
2. Then Unzip the file and check the name of the file according to the name of the file i set 3 varible which are globel.
3. According to variables i took 3 Data flow tasks. And its working well for the above specified problem.
4. Its Working for different Data flow tasks.

But i have another issue in this when i am using the flat file source name as dynamicly(Using Expression) It is giving me error about the Can not open the file.

Error "[Flat File Source [1]] Error: Cannot open the datafile "C:\Documents and Settings\XQN4P\Desktop\Inputs\Intraday\OPTION_DAILY_INTRADAY_ASIA20140212.csv".
"

Note this file is generated from Unziping the entered file by user.

Thank you

Comment: Actually The warning is "[Flat File Source [1]] Warning: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
". And when i see the file its empty.

Comment: I guess the script task that unzips the file hasn't unzipped it properly and/or is still active. Seriously you should optimise your VB code, not build this in SSIS.

Comment: Yeah the problem is in unziping..
No actually its a research project. My manager wants to know the time difference. If it goes fine theni will have a lot of things to do . Its a big bank...

Comment: Let me finish in saying: 1. I have seen many badly written data transfer VB apps that run really slowly that will run faster if they were written properly. 2. A VB app is the place to have user interaction, not SSIS.

Comment: Yeah i agree with you. But i am not having lot of user interaction. I am just getting filaname and type... And i heared SSIS is faster for big transformations..

Comment: "user interaction" is a boolean in this case - you either are or you aren't. Building something in another tool before working out the problem in the original tool is not the best way to go about it. Anyway good luck with it.