# Convert flatfile column to Datetime

Tags: ssis

Can anyone please help me, I have the following format that is coming in from a flatfile.

2013-12-30 00-20-18,114

I have to convert this as **datetime** and insert it into the database. I tried changing the ','(the milisec part) by finding it and using replace all with '.'
But well like you can see that does nt work.

Thank you

Comment: We can't see anything. Please post your code and any error you encountered.

Comment: Hey Shree.pat18, there is no code that I have implemented on it right now. The format that i get in the flat file is             'mm-dd-yyyy hh-mm-ss,ms' ..Need to convert this into datetime format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're starting with a string of  `2013-12-30 00-20-18,114`  and you need to get it into a format SQL Server can handle. The unambiguous format would be `2013-12-30T00:20:18.114` but the Expression language isn't going to like the T there in the middle so we'll have to settle for `2013-12-30 00:20:18.114` as our end state.

Your problem then becomes, how do I manipulate the supplied string into that format. You can use a script task but there's no need to pull out the big guns for something like this. Because the Expressions in SSIS can be a bit of a pain to work with, I'm going to have several Derived Columns in my data flow to allow me to take small steps toward my end goal

[image]

### OLE_SRC Date String

I have a basic query here to inject the supplied value

```
SELECT
    '' AS wtf
```

### DER Split to parts

This Derived Column is going to create two columns: DatePart and TimePart. The end result is that I will split this column where the whitespace is.

DatePart is defined as `SUBSTRING(wtf,1,10)` so this strips the first 10 characters out of the string.
TimePart is defined as `LTRIM(RIGHT(wtf,LEN(wtf) - 10))` so it takes the remaining characters, sans leading whitespace.

### DER Standardize

In this step, I'm going to make the time part into a standard format. I create a new column StandardTime and use the expression `REPLACE(REPLACE(TimePart,",","."),"-",":")`

### DER Concat

Here I put the two columns back together again as a shiny new column called `ConversionReady`. This expression is `DatePart + " " + StandardTime`

### Data Conversion

Here I cast my `ConversionReady` column to date [DT_DATE] datatype and call it `Copy of ConversionReady` because I'm lazy.

### OLE DB Destination

I created a table and mapped my wtf to SourceValue and "Copy of ConversionReady" to ConvertedValue.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.ConversionReady
(
    SourceValue varchar(30)
,   ConvertedValue datetime
);
```

### What is up with all those derived columns? Doesn't that slow thing down?

[No, not really](http://henkvandervalk.com/how-to-speed-up-ssis-derived-columns-transformations). It certainly makes it easier to debug than trying to do it all in a single expression since you have no debugging capabilities for Expressions.

Comment: How about using a Derived Column to add a new datetime column followed by a Script Transformation to convert it to a suitable format and return a datetime?

Comment: @shree.pat18 if I were using the script transformation, I'd just create the column there versus creating it in an upstream component just to change it in the next step.

Comment: This is the error I am getting [Data Conversion [41]] Error: Data conversion failed while converting column "DATE_PART" (151) to column "PROCESSED_Date_PART" (50).  The conversion returned status value 2 and status text "The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data.".

Comment: @billinkc Ah yes  I see.

Comment: @snp.it this solution works for the supplied data point. Could you update your question with more data

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when i mixed Date and Time as above in a string and then i tried to convert it in to DateTime. It was not possible.

Then i did it seperatlly. And added the time in to date using Date Add function.

I answered my own question please check it below link.

Feel free to ask any thing.
Here is [a Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21605109/data-conversion-in-ssis?noredirect=1#comment32661867_21605109)!