# Convert varchar to datetime using VB script

Tags: vb.net, datetime, ssis, varchar

I need to convert a date field which is in varchar format `(DDMMYYYY)` to DateTime using .Net. I have tried a number of solutions but all in vain. My source for that field is a flat file and my destination is a table. I am using the script in SSIS package.

Below is the sample:

The column SampleDate is in the `ddmmyyyy` format. I am converting it to `MM/dd/YYYY` in order to convert it to datetime format.

```
Dim retString1 As String
Dim slash As Char = ChrW(&H2F)
retString1 = Row.SampleDate.Substring(2, 2) & "/"
Dim retString2 As String
retString2 = Row.SampleDate.Substring(0, 2) & "/"
Dim retString3 As String
retString3 = Row.SampleDate.Substring(4, 4)
Dim retString4 As String
retString4 = retString1 & retString2 & retString3

Dim fromDt As Date = Convert.ToDateTime(retString4)
fromDt = Row.SampleDate
```

P.S. : I am not looking for SQL Query for the conversion so before commenting, please read the whole question thoroughly. I am looking for a VB code and not a SQL code.

Comment: You should really check that the answer has not already been provided before positing a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21833719/convert-flatfile-column-to-datetime

Comment: Dear BIDeveloper, if you think the answer is already there, let me know. Trust me I have tried everything, but my VB code is not converting the DDMMYYYY to YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS format.

Comment: While I don't doubt that the question of how to convert a string (from a flat/text file) to a variable of (sub) type Date has been asked before,  the answer "use convert from your sql server" is wrong.

Comment: That is not VBScript is looks more like VB.Net  especially with the use of `Convert.ToDateTime()` method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert a string to a datetime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634568/convert-a-string-to-a-datetime)

Comment: Now that the question has been corrected to reflect what is actually required - it is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634568/convert-a-string-to-a-datetime

Comment: If this is vb.net and not vbscript, then look up [Date.ParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just flip `fromdt = Row.SampleDate`

to

```
Row.SampleDate = fromdt
```

And your script should work but see below to simplify some if you want.

HOW TO DO IT WITHOUT A SCRIPT --see below for script method

You can make this a lot simpler for yourself if you use a `Derived Column` transformation instead!  The data conversion transformation doesn't work because it doesn't allow you to manipulate the value of the column, but rather only the data type.  But in the derived column you can cut up the string and cast the result as a date.

So Source to Derived Column to Destination in your data flow.

[image]

In the derived column your add a new column and use the following as the expression (replacing `DateString` with the `name of your column` containing the date in `ddMMyyyy` format)

Then use this as the `Expression`:

```
(DT_DATE)(SUBSTRING(DateString,3,2) + "/" + (LEFT(DateString,2) + "/" + RIGHT(DateString,4)))
```

The `(dt_date)` can be switched for another date format if you wish and that type cast will automatically set the `Data Type` on the `Derived Column`.  Then in your `destination` map the `new derived column` to the `destination column` instead of your original column from your `source`.

[image]

That's it your done, no scripts.

**HOW TO DO IT VIA A SCRIPT**

To address the route if you wanted to stay with a script and perhaps inject some additional logic rather than simple conversion you can do it through a `transformation` `script component` in a your `data flow task`.  It will take place of the `derived column` transformation above but essentially will do the same thing only through a script.  I am putting steps in here that I am guessing you already know some of in case someone else stumbles on the post.

- Add the script component when you do choose "transformation" and connect it with you source
- Open Script component and go to the "`Inputs and Outputs`" section and add an output to hold the new column and set the datatype.  A new column is necessary because you are changing data types

[image]

- go to "`Input Columns`" section and choose `SampleDate` column

[image]

- go back to "`Script`" section and choose Visual Basic as your script language.
- Click Edit Script to begin your coding.
- Scroll down till you find the sub `Input0_ProcessInputRow(ByVal Row...` this is where you will put your code.

This code works:

```
Public Overrides Sub Input0_ProcessInputRow(ByVal Row As Input0Buffer)

    If Not Row.SampleDate_IsNull Then

        Row.DerivedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(Row.SampleDate, "ddMMyyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

    End If
End Sub
```

As @Shiva in comments suggested you could expand this and use TryParseExact or wrap it in a try catch block so that if parsing the date fails it would simply clear/remove the value from the record and the import will continue.  I leave that up to you as handling invalid data is more a question of business requirements.

Comment: `That's it your done, no scripts. You of course can do it via a script but I don't see why would when the standard options are available to your`. Your solution assumed the "happy path" only. The source datefield is of type `varchar`. That means that it could have invalid data too. Using a script gives greater control in that you can do a `TryParse` on that field and convert to date only if that succeeds. This derived column approach would fail even if there is valid date, that is not EXACTLY in the `DDMMYYYY` format. That said, I have given a +1 for your efforts.

Comment: @Shiva the OP clearly said 1 format, and not mention of potential validity issues.  I can definitely see the reason to use script tasks for testing validity.  But then the question is if invalid what do you want to do, still import? That leads to what should the value be for an invalid date? Null what if destination doesn't allow for Nulls, import will still fail.....At some point decisions of validity of data need to be made and typically I always want them to fail until I can find pattern/discover ways of correcting invalid dates rather than succeed quietly. PS I use way more complex scripts

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. It makes sense now.

Comment: @Shiva I decided to add the script method as well.

Comment: Excellent! This makes it a complete answer now :)

Comment: Thanks a lot Matt and Shiva. I am a newbie in SSIS and that really did help. I am also getting junk values like ABC, NR etc in my SampleDate column. How do I handle it? Does SSIS support IIF function that we have in SSRS. Or do we have IsDate equivalent function?

Comment: Could you potentially have a delimiter problem causing the text to be in your date field?  Is the text always at the end or beginning of the date?  I would probably use the script task and do some string manipulation, but you can also  use a conditional syntax here is a link on how to do it in expressions in ssis. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141680.aspx

Answer (score 0):

To convert a string to a date in **VBScript** you either use [CDate()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dt118h2%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)
which does the conversion for you but depends on the current regional settings or [DateSerial()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1we4t8hy%28v=vs.84%29.aspx):

```
>> s = "13041953"
>> d = DateSerial(CInt(Right(s,4)), CInt(Mid(s,3,2)), CInt(Left(s,2)))
>> WScript.Echo s, TypeName(d), d
>>
13041953 Date 13.04.1953 (german locale)
```