# Change date format of data coming from flat file SSIS

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012, script-component, derived-column

I am reading data from a flat file and storing them in a OLE DB destination.
In the flat file, dates and in various formats
17/02/2014,
28-Apr-14,
30.06.14

I have used a Derived column transformation to check for empty columns and replace it with null. As far as I have seen SSIS and data base accepts 17/02/2014 format and 28-Apr-14, 30.06.14 are rejected.

I want to convert 28-Apr-14 and 30.06.14 to a valid format which DB accepts.

I have researched a bit and read that Script task can do it but I am not sure of the code how to check this.

Could you please guide which is the best way to do this.

Any suggestions/help is much appreciated.

Thanks
Rao

Comment: your best bet would be to store the same way as they are coming or sticking to same format for all the dates in flat file

Comment: how can I  insert different formats in one column

Comment: You can do it in a derived column, a script transformation or a T-SQL query. Personally I prefer T-SQL. What do you prefer? Also are you absolutely certain that the dd.mm.yy will never be in the form mm.dd.yy? (those crazy americans)

Comment: I can not implement all the possibilities but I will only to the formats mentioned above. I prefer derived column or script transformation as i am bit familiar with them. In Derived column how do I do it though?

Comment: @JoeC 's link shows you how to do it in T-SQL as his answer suggests and My answer on the same question shows you a SSIS Script Component method.  I personally find the script much simpler because there is less string manipulation and it doesn't require a staging table if you first need to load the data from another source into SQL.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSIS clean up date from csv file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38225475/ssis-clean-up-date-from-csv-file)

Answer (score 1):

Check out my answer on the following question.  This should work for you as well.

[SSIS clean up date from csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38225475/ssis-clean-up-date-from-csv-file/38226807#38226807)